# Mysql multiple sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I am created the three tables and list in the following table structures.

1) th_sales_inventory:

```
id    
user_id    
invoice_date   
increment  
invoice_num    
client_address 
total  
shiping    
roundoff   
company_id 
status 
created_date   
updated_date   
updated_by  
created_by
```

Table Data:
[image]

2) th_product

```
id 
cat_id
name  
description   
purchase_price
selling_price 
image 
company_id
status
created_date  
updated_date  
created_by
updated_by
```

Table Data:

[image]
3) th_sales_inventory_detail

```
id 
product_id
sales_inventory_id
selling_price 
qty   
amount
```

Table Data:

[image]

I created the sales invoice and values stored in the respective tables. I want to get each product sales with the total quantity, total amount based on the invoice date.

I am using following MySQL query but I do not get the result correctly.

```
SELECT p.id as pid,p.name, SUM(sid.qty) as sqty, SUM(total) AS sum,sid.qty, SUM(sid.qty * p.purchase_price) as pu_sum
FROM th_sales_inventory as si
    LEFT JOIN th_sales_inventory_detail as sid ON sid.sales_inventory_id = si.id
    LEFT JOIN th_product as p ON sid.product_id = p.id
WHERE `invoice_date` LIKE '2018-03-%' AND si.company_id = '1'
GROUP BY sid.product_id
```

Output:

```
pid name        sqty     sum     qty     pu_sum     
1   thaaimann   2.000   80.00   2.000   20.00000
2   tomoto1     15.000  340.00  2.000   150.00000
```

Comment: Where is your `invoice_date` field?

Comment: Your 1st and 3rd tables are identical. Typo?

Comment: Sorry I wrongly mentioned the table will edit the question

Comment: What does that mean that you don't get the results correctly? Do you get too many rows? Too few? Do the figures seem to high or too low? You want the totals per product in the date range? Or the totals per product and date in the date range?

Comment: Why do you outer join? Do you really expect `th_sales_inventory` that have no `th_sales_inventory_detail` and `th_sales_inventory_detail` where `product_id` is null? That doesn't seem to make any sense. Especially as you are grouping by product.

Comment: The product is not null. Could you please explain clear or else update the mysql query

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is not a normal inner join, but a left outer join. We only use it when we want to keep data from a table that may have no match in another. Change all `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` in the query to make it clear this is not the case with your data.

Comment: And we still don't know what the exact problem with your query is. Why `si.company_id = '1'` and not `si.company_id = 1`? Is the `company_id` a string? Why `invoice_date LIKE '2018-03-%'`? Is `invoice_date` a string? It shouldn't be. But `LIKE` is a string operation. You may want `year(invoice_date) = 2018 and month(invoice_date) = 3` instead.

Comment: My guess is product is not unique.

Comment: I need to sales report based on product name(product id) based on invoice month

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Again: How is your result different from what you want? I suggest you show sample data, the result you get and the result you expect instead.

Comment: As product id not unique in sales inventory detail table. In the product table product id is primary

Comment: Shall i connect to skype?

Comment: No. Just answer the question. Edit your request to make clear how the result you get is different from what you want.

Comment: I think we all understand what you are trying to do but we need a bit more details please add your table schemas as text to your question by running show create table and copying and pasting the output. Also add sample data with expected result.

Comment: Hello,
We have updated the question and please check now

Comment: We cannot use images, some people may not even be able to see them and you haven't added your table definitions. You are really making it hard for yourself.I'm out.